# SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement in Rails 4 via connection.execute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO order_items (cart_id, quantity, product_id) SELECT cart_id, quantity, product_id FROM cart_items WHERE cart_id = ? ", cart_id)
```

I am running the above code in a controller action to shift data between tables.

The terminal shows the following code executing

```
nqjeV4HNx5So4Zx2x-81qg (9.3ms)  INSERT INTO order_items (cart_id, quantity, product_id) SELECT cart_id, quantity, product_id FROM cart_items WHERE cart_id = ?
```

Even though the code runs without raising any errors no data is moved from the `CartItem` model to the `OrderItem` model. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

I am modeling my query according to the following code example: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO order_items (cart_id, quantity, product_id) SELECT cart_id, quantity, product_id FROM cart_items WHERE cart_id = ? ", cart_id)
```

`execute` method doesn't allow this interpolation technique with the question mark and a ruby variable. The first parameter to this method should be a completed SQL query. You should do it like so:

```
"... WHERE cart_id = '#{cart_id}'"
```

But this is dangerous, because it allow for SQL injection. Before interpolating `cart_id` variable you should ensure that it contains only digits.

Actually, you don't need to use pure SQL queries here, because you can use ActiveRecord to achieve your goal:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  CartItem.where(cart_id: cart_id).each do |cart_item|
    OrderItem.create(cart_id: cart_item.cart_id, quantity: cart_item.quantity, product_id: cart_item.product_id)
  end
end
```

Or you can use https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import gem:

```
cart_items = CartItem.where(cart_id: cart_id).pluck(:cart_id, :quantity, :product_id)
OrderItem.import([:cart_id, :quantity, :product_id], cart_items)
```

Comment: after making this change I am receiving the following error `SQLException: no such column: ugMc7c9DL5q8LgQlzn5fCw: INSERT INTO order_items (cart_id, quantity, product_id) SELECT cart_id, quantity, product_id FROM cart_items WHERE cart_id = ugMc7c9DL5q8LgQlzn5fCw`

Comment: Add quotes around `#{cart_id}`.

Comment: I think it may issue about column. Check your table and column

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still have an issue. When I add double quotes (") it raises an error in my IDE. When I add single quotes `'#{cart_id}'` I get the following error `SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: order_items.created_at: INSERT INTO order_items (cart_id, quantity, product_id) SELECT cart_id, quantity, product_id FROM cart_items WHERE cart_id = 'ugMc7c9DL5q8LgQlzn5fCw'`

Comment: You have NOT NULL constraint on one of the `order_items` columns. It means that this column cannot be `NULL`, but when you do this `INSERT` you don't specify a value for this column. This might be one of these three columns or some other column. Check `schema.rb` and see which column in `order_items` has `null: false`.

Comment: The table has an index on a column named `order_id`. Is it correct that an index column cannot have a NULL value? Is it possible to combine an INSERT INTO SELECT statement with a INSERT INTO VALUES statement? For example: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO order_items (cart_id, quantity, product_id, order_id) SELECT cart_id, quantity, product_id FROM cart_items WHERE cart_id = '#{cart_id}' VALUES ('#{@order.id}') ")` The first three columns would get filled with data using the SELECT statement and the fourth (order_id) would get filled using the VALUES statement.

Comment: Try it like so: `INSERT INTO order_items (cart_id, quantity, product_id, order_id) SELECT cart_id, quantity, product_id, '#{@order.id}' FROM ...` without `VALUES`. (if order.id is integer then remove quotes around it)

Comment: A general comment. I like using things like `#{cart_id.inspect}` or `#{cart_id.to_json}` to escape the values, and handle any possible quote issues. Whenever I see `'#{cart_id}'` I cringe a little at the possible SQL injection, etc.